# Override Wagtail Page.get_url()?

Tags: wagtail

In an attempt to use only the Wagtail `Page` tree for the nav structure, I have declared the following so that a link can be rendered if desired rather than a page url:

```
class Node(Page):
  
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Node (no content or link)'

    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank='True', help_text='Optional.  Leave blank if serving as a parent page')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('link')
    ]

    def get_url(self, **kwargs):
        if self.link != '':
            return self.link
        else:
            return super().get_url(self, **kwargs)
```

In the template I have tried both `{{ item.url }}` and `{{ item.specific.url }}` where `item` is an item in the page tree that is being iterated.  The item's url as defined by Wagtail's `Page.get_url()` function is always rendered, and the `def get_url()` I've defined is never being executed.

I am aware of Wagtail Menus but was trying to not have another dependency in this project, so aside from whether or not the above is the best architecture, what am I missing in getting this to work?

---

To follow up here, I have followed [these instructions](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#customising-url-patterns-for-a-page-model), and on the `class Node(Page)` model I now have the following in place of `def get_url`:

```
def get_url_parts(self, *args, **kwargs):
    site_id, root_url, page_path = super().get_url_parts(*args, **kwargs)
    # return an alternative page_path if link has a value
    if self.link.strip() != '':
        page_path = self.link

    return site_id, root_url, page_path
```

I found that I still had to render the page urls with `item.specific.get_url`.  `item.url` would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `url` property on the Page model is [defined by this line of code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/454002fbd777e0d4e60e874a51ba78a2794f9619/wagtail/core/models.py#L1701):

```
url = property(get_url)
```

i.e. define a property `url` that wraps a call to the `get_url` function *as it existed at that moment when that line of code is run* - namely, the default implementation of Page.get_url. Even if you override `get_url` on the Node model, the Node model's `url` property will still be pointing at the original definition.

If you add the line `url = property(get_url)` after your definition of `get_url`, or call `{{ item.specific.get_url }}` directly on your template, you should hopefully see the desired behaviour.

As per the docs, [`get_url_parts`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_url_parts) is the recommended method to override if you're setting up a custom URL scheme, as this contains the shared logic common to all the URL accessors (`url`, `get_url`, `full_url`, `relative_url`).